# Rechats Cartesian Grid - gridlines as electrocardiogram

Tags: reactjs, recharts

What I would like to achieve is this:
[The ECG Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Dn2.png)
How do I configure the CartesianGrid to have a grid as expected to a electrocardiogram (ECG)?
One small box is 0.02 seconds and 1 large box is 0.1 seconds when the ECG paper speed is 50mm/s